# Как расположить футер под блоками?

Tags: html, css

Есть div head, который сверху
Есть div leftbox и rightbox
Есть div footer, который не отодвигается вниз, а находится под leftbox или rightbox...
как сделать, чтобы footer следовал за ними?

```
.head{
   position: relative;
   width:1000;
   height: 130;
   background: #d3c8c8;  
}

.cont{
   position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: 1000px;
    background: #ccc;
}

.leftbox{
    position: relative;
   width:750;
   height: auto;
   background: #d6cece;
   padding:10;
   float:left;
   border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.rightbox{
    position: relative;
   width:220;
   height: auto;
   background: #f2efef;
   float: left;
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.foot{
    position: relative;
   height: 50;
    width: 1000;
   background: #ffffff;

}
```

Comment: предоставьте код, с которым испытываете проблемы. и опишите более раскрыто проблему по возможности

Comment: У меня два блока находят на одной высоте рядом друг с другом, слева контент будет выводиться, а справа меню. Если я задаю значение height определенное в пикселах, то футер под блоками сразу, а если делаю его auto, то находится на том же уровне, что и блоки. Так как я буду публиковать очень большие статьи, то как сделать, чтобы футер был за этими блоками.
если задам высоту конетнту 2000 пикселов, а размещу информации больше, то футер залез на инфо.

Comment: прежде всего, вам вряд ли нужно выставлять всем блокам `position` - этим параметром вы только запутаете себя. кроме этого, оберните свой контент в отдельный тег, тогда футер не будет на том же уровне, что и контент. примерно так:     <header class="head"></header>
<main class="cont">
  <div class="leftbox"></div>
  <div class="rightbox"></div>
</main>
<footer class="foot"></footer>    и добавьте своему футеру стиль `clear: both;` - это отменит обтекание после `float`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Везде работает и после ul,ol

```
.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{display:table;content:' ';}

.clearfix:after{clear:both;}
```

---

```
<style>
.head{
position: relative;
width:1000;
height: 130;
background: #d3c8c8;  
}
.cont{
position: relative;
height: auto;
width: 1000px;
background: #ccc;
}
.leftbox{
position: relative;
width:750;
height: auto;
background: #d6cece;
padding:10;
float:left;
border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.rightbox{
position: relative;
width:220;
height: auto;
background: #f2efef;
float: left;
border: 1px solid yellow;
}
.foot{
position: relative;
height: 50;
width: 1000;
background: #ffffff;
}
.clearfix:before,.clearfix:after{display:table;content:' ';}
.clearfix:after{clear:both;}
</style>  
<div class="head">1</div>
<div class="leftbox">1</div>
<div class="rightbox">1</div>
<div class="Clearfix"></div>
<div class="footer">foooooooooooooooter</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. В html5 есть специальный тег - footer. Подробнее о нём рассказано, например, [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/html/footer)
2. Прибивать футер к низу можно разными способами, один из распространённых - использовать wrapper:

html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
   <p>Your website content here.</p>
   <div class="push"></div>
 </div>
 <div class="footer">
     <p>Copyright (c) 2016</p>
 </div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0;
}
html, body {
height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
min-height: 100%;
height: auto !important;
height: 100%;
margin: 0 auto -4em;
}
.footer, .push {
height: 4em;
}
```

Так же ознакомьтесь с различными нюансами: [Раз](http://habrahabr.ru/post/151320/), [два](http://habrahabr.ru/post/66805/)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.head {
  position: relative;
  width: 1000;
  height: 130;
  background: #d3c8c8;
}

.cont {
  position: relative;
  height: auto;
  width: 1000px;
  background: #ccc;
}

.leftbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 750px;
  height: auto;
  background: #d6cece;
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.rightbox {
  position: relative;
  width: 220px;
  height: auto;
  background: #f2efef;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
}

.foot {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 1000px;
  background: #ffffff;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<header class="head">HEADER: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit, aspernatur corporis reiciendis magnam quae!</header>
<main class="cont">
  <div class="leftbox">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur odit, aperiam eos tempore suscipit, modi maxime ipsam soluta deleniti perferendis provident, voluptatibus amet nemo id reiciendis quae quibusdam totam nobis.</div>
  <div class="rightbox">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Repudiandae earum, modi. Eveniet iure suscipit enim esse sint dolorem illo unde, in, perspiciatis temporibus amet corporis sed alias nisi expedita, adipisci!</div>
</main>
<footer class="foot">FOOTER: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed fuga nesciunt dicta facere explicabo. Reiciendis suscipit sed voluptatum consectetur culpa quidem, assumenda tempore blanditiis corporis veniam in cum, vel natus.</footer>
```